# Is it possible to format the email body when sending PDF form as an attachment?

Tags: javascript, forms, formatting, email-attachments

I'm new to JavaScript & am send a PDF form as an email attachment using the following:

> this.mailDoc({
>   cTo: "someone@somewhere.com",
>   cSubject: "Subject line goes here",
>   cMsg: "The message body of the email goes here.\nThis is another line in the body."
>   })

My question: Is there a way to format part of the text of the email body w/ italics and/or bold? For example:

> cMsg: "The message body of the email goes ***here***.

Comment: The first thing I'd try is basic HTML: `"The message body of the email goes <b>here</b>"`.

Comment: I tried <em> and <i> - In both cases the tag showed up in the body of the email,  like: The message body of the email goes <em>here</em>.

Comment: You probably have to set the header to `Content-Type: text/html`, but I couldn't find any documentation about `.mailDoc()`.